# Access protected (from export) private key in windows certificate store

Tags: certificates, windows

I have created a CSR with the option to disallow the export of the private key. Can I still access it?

If not, how is it protected?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Mimikat'z crypto module](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki/module-~-crypto). Most A/Vs flag Mimikatz as a "threat",  add appropriate exclusion.